# Congruence for complementary Bell numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, partitions

The [Bell numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplementaryBellNumber.html) $B(n)$ can be given as a sum of the (signed) [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplementaryBellNumber.html) $S(n,k)$ as $B(n)=\sum_{k=0}^nS(n,k)$. There are also the so-called [complementary Bell numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplementaryBellNumber.html) defined by
$$B_1(n):=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kS(n,k).$$

> **QUESTION.** Given any prime $p$ and a positive integer $k$, is it true that
>   $$B_1(n+p^k)\equiv B_1(n+1)-kB_1(n) \mod p?$$

**EDIT.** In the definition of $B_1(n)$ there was a typo: $(-1)^n$ was meant to be $(-1)^k$.

Comment: You have tested this for some range of values of $p$ and $k$? or you have some other reason for believing it?

Comment: Thanks for asking. This has been well-tested for many values of $p$ and $k$, so I'm a "believer" my evidence. :-)

Comment: (You might also edit the title to make it more informative, e.g. "Conjecture: congruence for complementary Bell numbers".)

Comment: Thanks, I altered the "catchy" title to a more straight-forward one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The definition of the complementary Bell numbers should be
$$B_1(n):=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kS(n,k).$$

Define the polynomials $B_n(x)$ by 
$$B_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nx^kS(n,k),$$
so $B_1(n) = B_n(-1)$.
These polynomials are called *Bell polynomials* or *exponential polynomials*.  Christian Radoux proved the congruence
$$ B_{n+p^k}(x) \equiv B_{n+1}(x) + (x^p+x^{p^2}+\cdots+x^{p^k})B_n(x) \pmod p,$$
where congruence is coefficientwise as polynomials in $x$. (See Anne Gertsch and  Alain M. Robert, 
[Some congruences concerning the Bell numbers](http://www.emis.de/journals/BBMS/Bulletin/bul964/Robert-Gertsch.pdf). 
Bull. Belg. Math. Soc. Simon Stevin 3 (1996), no. 4, 467–475,  for references and another proof.)
The congruence for the complementary Bell numbers is the case $x=-1$. (Touchard's congruence is the case $x=1$.)

Comment: Thank you for the reference. The results are interesting because I see that both Bell numbers can be treated uniformly. Up-voted.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you've rediscovered "Touchard's congruence" (the case $k=1$) and the
generalization [attributed by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Modular_arithmetic) to Hurst and Schultz (arXiv:[0906.0696](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0696)).

Comment: Looking more carefully, I see that Touchard's congruence is for the
ordinary Bell numbers $B(n)$, not the complementary Bell numbers $B_1(n)$.
But there's a good chance that an elementary proof of generalized Touchard
for $B(n)$ can be adapted to give the corresponding congruence for $B_1(n)$.

Comment: (1) Yes, the numbers and the results have close semblance but different; (2) I wish to see a more elegant proof, perhaps one that puts both numbers under the same umbrella.

Comment: Now that the question has been answered properly I should probably make this into a comment and then delete my "answer" which turned out to answer a different question.

Comment: Please do not delete. It's a good reference for people who wish to explore. Instead, edit your first line only, saying "a similar or complementary result can be found ..."

Comment: The references (to Wikipedia and Hurst-Schultz) can still appear in the comment.  I thought this would be better because the comment would be seen before **Ira Gessel**'s answer (which refers to Touchard's congruence without explanation).

Comment: Okay then, I understand.